# Жители страны Мьянма или страны Мьянмы?

Tags: окончания

*Жители далеко не богатой азиатской страны Мьянма больше всех в мире жертвуют деньги на благотворительность.*

Answer (score 3):

Жители далеко не богатой азиатской страны **Мьянма** больше всех в мире жертвуют деньги на благотворительность.

**По Розенталю:** При наличии родового имени склоняются **известные географические названия**, например: у города Флоренции. Склонение малоизвестных имен может привести к непониманию названия: страна Мьянма или Мьянмы.

При отсутствии родового наименования "Мьянма" склоняется по образцу существительных  1-го скл.: **Мьянма** (раньше называлась **Бирмой**)  — государство в Юго-Восточной Азии. Путеводитель **по Мьянме:** заметки **о Мьянме**,  фотографии **Мьянмы**, бронирование отелей в **Мьянме.**

Можно отметить, что прежнее название могло бы склоняться: азиатской страны Бирмы.

Comment: Почему прежнее могло, а нынешнее не может?

Comment: Бирма - известное название, с ним трудно ошибиться.   В любом случае, как говорит Розенталь, склоняемость при наличии родового слова - это  только рекомендации,  обобщение опыта,  а не жесткие правила.

Comment: _**Sibylla**: При наличии родового имени… склонение малоизвестных имен может привести к непониманию названия: **страна Мьянма или Мьянмы**. При отсутствии родового наименования "Мьянма" склоняется… фотографии Мьянмы_. === Сравните два предложения: _"Фотографии страны Мьянмы"_ и _"Фотографии Мьянмы"_.  **Вопрос** такой: почему Вы считаете, что в первом случае непонимание названия страны возможно, а во втором (при исключении родового имени) это название будет пониматься однозначно?

Answer (score 3):

C родовым понятием *"страна"* случай особый: в отличие от "города" или "реки" его редко употребляют перед названиями "известных" стран. Выражения "*в стране России*" или "*в стране Мексике*" в обычном контексте не употребляются. Сама "**известность**" в таких случаях **относительна** - она соотносится с аудиторией, к которой адресуются: если уж употребляют слово "страна", то обычно хотят донести её название для тех, кто может его не сразу вспомнить, а *условно малоизвестное* название логично не склонять - так меньше шансов для его неправильного восприятия. Поэтому в сочетании с понятием "страна", тем более с напоминающим уточнением "азиатская" (или иная), естественнее **не склонять** даже *известные* названия (африканской страны Бенин, азиатской страны Мьянма).

Comment: Жители далеко не самой богатой азиатской страны Бирмы больше всех в мире жертвуют деньги на благотворительность. Разве здесь не нужно склонять название?

Comment: Здесь сравнительная известность названия делает неестественным порядок слов в варианте со склонением. Если его не менять, нужно хотя бы пунктуацией оправдать будто бы представляющее страну многословие: _Жители далеко не самой богатой азиатской страны, Бирмы, больше всех в мире..._ Или можно изменить порядок слов: _Жители Бирмы, далеко не самой богатой азиатской страны, больше всех в мире..._ Если же просто "азиатской страны Бирма" - склонять не нужно: такое упоминание явно представляет страну, для кого-то - новую.

Comment: *...такое упоминание явно представляет страну, для кого-то - новую.*  По-моему, не обязательно представляет: что не самая богатая, просто уточняет для связи с дальнейшим, а что азиатская, просто напоминает для тех, кто не очень твёрдо помнит и мог подзабыть, где Бирма.